# Error when trying to add splash screen - android app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm an android newbie

I was following this tutorial [Android splash screen howto](http://www.onlymobilepro.com/2013/01/16/android-beginner-creating-splash-screen/), it's a little outdated, but anyways.

I just add the new layout file `splash.xml` into res/layout, and then the image into drawable/mdpi, then I change the main image into MainActivity.java, ie:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

Being `activity_main` the name of the default layout, activity_main.xml, and `splash` the name of the other layout called splash.xml.

But application stops, says the application has unfortunately stopped, and I can't even access it.

I don't know what am I missing here, here's the interesting code on MainActivity.java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerImg);
    relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)
                                       findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
  //  cameraSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480));
    cameraSurfaceHolder = cameraSurfaceView.getHolder();
    cameraSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
//    cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.
  //                                               SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);




    btnCapture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         camera.takePicture(cameraShutterCallback, 
                                       cameraPictureCallbackRaw,
                                       cameraPictureCallbackJpeg);
      }
    });
  }
```

My `activity_main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
            android:layout_width="1276px"
            android:layout_height="745px"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/surfaceView1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/surfaceView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
            android:src="@drawable/mark3" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/camera" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My `splash.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Maybe I should use the same `activity_main.xml` for this purposes, not really sure...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Logcat:

```
3774-3774/com.kkoci.photo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.kkoci.photo/com.kkoci.photo.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.kkoci.photo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is your error? What does logcat say? Always post your logcat.

Comment: Please post your error log

Comment: Where is the error log...?

Comment: In your `splash.xml` where is `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Added the error log... sorry folks, I forgot

Comment: Have you checked the below answer and my comment?

Comment: There is no RelativeLayout in your splash.xml.....consider the above mentioned tutorial to create a splash screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerImg);
relativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
```

these are the views present in your `activity_main` xml file.. when you change your layout file why you are accessing these?

Comment: Maybe that's the problem, you see, I'm just following the tutorial, but that is based on a Hello World type app, I think I should add support for splash screen on the same activity_main file

Comment: I'm accessing these, because this is an overlay image camera app, a simple one I'm building

Comment: There nothing called splash screen in android .. its just that you have to implement it like an activity .. splashscreen is just a activity like other activity ..

Comment: once you make a seperate activity for splash dont forget to declare it in the manifest

Comment: I know, it's just a way to call it, like a "loading" screen or something... Yeah I see... I'll make a new Activity for it, then, thank you both!

Comment: @NeoVe thats better :)